# Angulajs populate variable from $http get

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-directive

I've this directive that validate asynchronously username from an array (usernames). How can i use an http call that query my db instead of static array?

```
app.directive('username', function($q, $timeout) {
return {
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
  var usernames = ['Jim', 'John', 'Jill', 'Jackie'];

  ctrl.$asyncValidators.username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {

    if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
      // consider empty model valid
      return $q.when();
    }

    var def = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function() {
      // Mock a delayed response
      if (usernames.indexOf(modelValue) === -1) {
        // The username is available
        def.resolve();
      } else {
        def.reject();
      }

    }, 2000);

    return def.promise;
  };
}
};
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject `$http` in to your directive function, make the AJAX call in your link and either resolve or reject your promise based on your AJAX call's response.

```
app.directive('username', function($q, $timeout, $http) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {


        ctrl.$asyncValidators.username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {

          if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
           // consider empty model valid
          return $q.when();
          }

          var def = $q.defer();

          $http.get('your-rest-api/users/'+modelValue).then(function() {
           // Found the user
           def.reject();
         }, function() {
            // User not found
           def.resolve();
         });


       return def.promise;
      };
   } // end of link fn
  }; // end of DDO
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arkantos. What i have to return by api if I found user? Do you thik it's possible to have more than found and not found (ex. user found, user not found, user suspended)?

Comment: Yes it depends on the response from your API. You can always set a `status` property in your response as `found/not found/suspended` and handle that accordingly in the success/error callback. All 2XX http status codes will invoke success callback - 1st param in `then()`. Any other status code will invoke error callback - 2nd param

Comment: Your REST API should return user objects, not just user names if you need a status, eg. {name="Jim", status="suspended", privileges="admin"}

Comment: Ok Jander. I understand. But after, how i can manage these object. I think my directive is not enough. Have you a sample, or something?